# Does Python input need to be surrounded by quotes?

Tags: python, string, input, quotes

**This should be simple, but I'm having trouble finding an explanation. Here's my code:**

```
 car = input("What kind of car would you like? ")
    print("\nLet me see if I can find a {}".format(car))
```

**The terminal then prompts for a type of car.**

**I enter: Ford**

**I get this error:**

```
What kind of car would you like? Ford
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rental_car.py", line 1, in <module>
    car = input("What kind of car would you like? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Ford' is not defined
```

**If I enter: 'Ford'**
**The program runs as expected.**

**Does Python require quotes on input values other than numbers?**

**Any help is appreciated!**

Comment: nope, maybe compiler issues

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 2.x, the function [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) evaluates whatever the user enters. As the docs state, this is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))`.

So on Python 2.x you should use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.

Or, for compatibility between Python 2 and 3, you can use [`six.moves.input`](https://six.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: raw_input solves this problem, thank you!